# Obtain tsv from text with a specific pattern

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, file, structure

I'm a biologist and I need to take information on a text file
I have a file with plain text like that:

```
12018411
Comparison of two timed artificial insemination (TAI) protocols for management of first insemination postpartum. 
  TAI|timed artificial insemination|0.999808
Two estrus-synchronization programs were compared and factors influencing their success over a year were evaluated. All cows received a setup injection of PGF2alpha at 39 +/- 3 d postpartum. Fourteen days later they received GnRH, followed in 7 d by a second injection of PGF2alpha. Cows (n = 523) assigned to treatment 1 (modified targeted breeding) were inseminated based on visual signs of estrus at 24, 48, or 72 h after the second PGF2alpha injection. Any cow not observed in estrus was inseminated at 72 h. Cows (n = 440) assigned to treatment 2 received a second GnRH injection 48 h after the second PGF2alpha, and all were inseminated 24 h later. Treatment, season of calving, multiple birth, estrual status at insemination, number of occurrences of estrus before second PGF2alpha, prophylactic use of PGF2alpha, retained fetal membranes, and occurrence of estrus following the setup PGF2alpha influenced success. Conception rate was 31.2% (treatment 1) and 29.1% (treatment 2). A significant interaction occurred between protocol and estrual status at insemination. Cows in estrus at insemination had a 45.8% (treatment 1) or 35.4% (treatment 2) conception rate. The conception rate for cows not expressing estrus at insemination was 19.2% (treatment 1) and 27.7% (treatment 2). Provided good estrous detection exists, modified targeted breeding can be as successful as other timed artificial insemination programs. Nutritional, environmental, and management strategies to reduce postpartum disorders and to minimize the duration of postpartum anestrus are critical if synchronization schemes are used to program first insemination after the voluntary waiting period. 
    
8406022
Deletion of the beta-turn/alpha-helix motif at the exon 2/3 boundary of human c-Myc leads to the loss of its immortalizing function. 
The protein product (c-Myc) of the human c-myc proto-oncogene carries a beta-turn/alpha-helix motif at the exon2/exon3 boundary. The amino acid (aa) sequence and secondary structure of this motif are highly conserved among several nuclearly localized oncogene products, c-Myc, N-Myc, c-Fos, SV40 large T and adenovirus (Ad) Ela. Removal of this region from Ad E1a results in the loss of the transforming properties of the virus without destroying its known transregulatory functions. In order to analyse whether deletion of the above-mentioned region from c-Myc has a similar effect on its transformation activity, we constructed a deletion mutant (c-myc delta) lacking the respective aa at the exon2/exon3 boundary. In contrast to the c-myc wild-type gene product, constitutive expression of c-myc delta does not lead to the immortalization of primary mouse embryo fibroblast cells (MEF cells). This result indicates that c-Myc and Ad El a share a common domain which is involved in the transformation process by both oncogenes. 
  aa|amino acid|0.99818
  Ad|adenovirus|0.96935
  MEF cells|mouse embryo fibroblast cells|0.994648
```

The first line is the id, the second line is the title, the third line used to be the abstract (sometimes there are abbreviations) and the lasts lines (if there are) are abbreviations with double space, the abbreviation, the meaning, and a number. You can see :

```
  GA|general anesthesia|0.99818
```

Then there is a line in blank and start again: ID, Title, Abstract, Abbreviations or ID, Title, Abbreviations, Abstract.
And I need to take this data and convert to a TSV file like that:

```
12018411  TAI  timed artificial insemination
8406022   aa   amino acids
8406022   Ad   adenovirus
...      ...    ...
```

First column ID, second column Abbreviation, and third column Meaning of this abbreviation.
I tried to convert first in a Dataframe and then convert to TSV but I don't know how take the information of the text with the structure I need.
And I tried with this code too:

```
from collections import namedtuple
import pandas as pd

Item= namedtuple('Item', 'ID')
items = []

with open("identify_abbr-out.txt", "r", encoding='UTF-8') as f:
    lines= f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line== '\n':
            ID= ¿nextline?
        if line.startswith("  "):
            Abbreviation = line
            items.append(Item(ID, Abbreviation))

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(items, columns=['ID', 'Abbreviation'])
```

But I don't know how to read the next line and the code not found because there are some lines in blank in the middle between the corpus and the title sometimes.

I'm using python 3.8

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `test.txt` has your input data, I used simple file read functions to process the data -

```
file1 = open('test.txt', 'r') 
Lines = file1.readlines() 
outputlines = []
outputline=""
counter = 0
for l in Lines:
    if l.strip()=="":
        outputline = ""
        counter = 0
    elif counter==0:
        outputline = outputline + l.strip() + "|"
        counter = counter + 1
    elif counter==1:
        counter = counter + 1
    else:
        if len(l.split("|"))==3 and l[0:2]=="  " :
            outputlines.append(outputline + l.strip() +"\n")
        counter = counter + 1
        
file1 = open('myfile.txt', 'w') 
file1.writelines(outputlines) 
file1.close()
```

Here file is read, line by line, a counter is kept and reset when there is a blank line, and ID is read in just next line. If there are 3 field "|" separated row, with two spaces in beginning, row is exported with ID